# Why do I end up running CakePHP's cake command when I want to run the Coffeescript cake command?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, cakephp, coffeescript

I'm trying to run the `givenwhenthen` node module on Ubuntu 12.04 for the first time and I've followed the instructions for setup listed under the "Running Stories" header on their site [here.](http://mulabs.io/givenwhenthen)

I've added the task `test:acceptance` to my cakefile in `/~/node_modules/givenwhenthen/examples/`, like so:

```
task 'test:acceptance', 'Runs the acceptance tests', (options = {}) ->
  givenwhenthen.runner.runStories(options)
```

When I run `cake` from that same directory I get the following paths listed:

```
CakePHP v2.2.2 Console
App: examples
Path: /home/kyoob/node_modules/givenwhenthen/examples/
Root: /home/kyoob/node_modules/givnwhenthen
Core: /usr/share/php/cakephp/lib
```

I do not see `test:acceptance` under "Available Shells" and I don't see an "Available Tasks" section at all.  Should that be listed here?

When I run `cake test:acceptance` from this directory here is the message I get:

```
Shell class Test:acceptanceShell could not be found.
#0 /usr/share/php/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(191): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('test:acceptance')
#1 /usr/share/php/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /usr/share/php/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/cake.php(43): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
```

I've tried with and without `sudo` to the same effect.  I am new to the world of compiling CoffeeScript files, so I fear this is a rookie mistake on my part.  Am I trying to compile from the wrong directory?  Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### These are not the cakes you're looking for

```
When I run cake from that same directory I get the following paths listed:
CakePHP v2.2.2 Console
```

This means that  you're running [*CakePHP*'s cake cli](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#the-cakephp-console).

```
When I run cake test:acceptance ...
```

This syntax means you're *trying* to run the [coffeescript `cake`](http://jashkenas.github.io/coffee-script/documentation/docs/cake.html) command (the syntax for both commands is not the same). You can verify which command you're calling by running:

```
which cake
```

### Fix your paths

At a guess `/usr/share/php/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console` is in your path, and that means that when you type `cake` with no path it will find CakePHP's cake script. It's best to correct your `$PATH` removing CakePHP and therefore avoid ambiguity.

#### To run coffeescript's cake

When you want to run the coffeescript cake command - use the coffeescript cake command:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/cake test:acceptance
```

Or, once your `$PATH` is correct and since coffeescript installs it system-wide by default, you can just use it without a path:

```
$ cake test:acceptance
```

#### To run CakePHP's cake

If you want to run *CakePHP*'s cli (in the question you do not) - do so in the app folder, with a relative path:

```
$ cd /my/app
$ Console/cake
```

This command will only work if you're in your app folder, it is not dependent on your `$PATH`.

If in doubt use absolute paths to the executables but recognise that there are **two** scripts named cake if you're using CakePHP and coffeescript and they are **completely different and incompatible**, so passing acceptable arguments from one to the other will quite simply never work.

Comment: When you advise not to put `/usr/share/php/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/` in my path, where do you mean I should leave that out?  When I type the command in?  In my specific case would I go to `/~/node_modules/givenwhenthen/examples/` and run `/usr/share/php/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/cake test:acceptance`?  Sorry for being so literal.

Comment: I've removed it from my path, but won't running it from `Console/Cake` get me the shared php install anyway instead of the coffeescript command?  I thought I didn't want to run the CakePHP cli?

Comment: On top of it all I checked `/usr/bin/` and it had both `cake` commands in there, so even calling it directly from its path was getting the other command.  Problem solved.  Thanks!